# dataframe with variable name and variables in the same column

Tags: r, dataframe, html-table

I've created a script that scraps data from a HTML table, however, the variable and variable name are in the same column.

```
 
1   GESS ID:
2       5
3     Internal ID:
4       5
5     Identifiers:
6        5
7     Surname:
8       Dummy
9     Firstname:
10      Test
11    Sex:
12      M
```

How can I separate them in different columns?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have name and value in alternate cells you can use vector recycling to bring them in separate columns.

If your data is called `df` and column name is `V1` do :

```
result <- data.frame(Name = df$V1[c(TRUE, FALSE)], Value = df$V1[c(FALSE, TRUE)])
result

#          Name Value
#1     GESS ID:     5
#2 Internal ID:     5
#3 Identifiers:     5
#4     Surname: Dummy
#5   Firstname:  Test
#6         Sex:     M
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("GESS ID:", "5", "Internal ID:", "5", "Identifiers:",
"5", "Surname:", "Dummy", "Firstname:", "Test", "Sex:", "M")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```